# Python - Get waveform/amplitude of mp3

Tags: python, audio, mp3

I was hoping I could find a way to get the amplitude data from an mp3 in python. Similar to audacity but I do not want a visual, a simple array of values will do. I want my code to react to sound at certain points when it gets louder. I am using pygame to play the audio and was trying to convert it to a sndarray but it was only giving me the first 0.00018 seconds. Anyway I can get the whole mp3? It does not have to be real time as I would like to be able to react ahead of time anyway and will keep track of my position using pygame.

I am building [this cloud](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-cloud-lamp-sound-reactive-lightning/) using a raspberry pi instead for other features. I already have the lighting work and need it to react to the lightning, lightshowpi is not an option sadly. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:
So this is what I have so far thanks to coder-don. It works, but i hangs on the while loop. I do not know why. The mp3 I am using is rather long, could that be the issue?

```
import os, sys
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject
Gst.init()
GObject.threads_init()

def get_peaks(filename):
global do_run

pipeline_txt = (
    'filesrc location="%s" ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! '
    'audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=22050,endianness=1234,'
    'width=32,depth=32,signed=(bool)TRUE !'
    'level name=level interval=1000000000 !'
    'fakesink' % filename)
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_txt)

level = pipeline.get_by_name('level')
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()

peaks = []
do_run = True

def show_peak(bus, message):
    global do_run
    if message.type == Gst.MESSAGE_EOS:
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        do_run = False
        return
    # filter only on level messages
    if message.src is not level or \
       not message.structure.has_key('peak'):
        return
    peaks.append(message.structure['peak'][0])

# connect the callback
bus.connect('message', show_peak)

# run the pipeline until we got eos
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
ctx = GObject.MainContext()
while ctx and do_run:
    ctx.iteration()

return peaks

def normalize(peaks):
    _min = min(peaks)
    print(_min)
    _max = max(peaks)
    print(_max)
    d = _max - _min
    return [(x - _min) / d for x in peaks]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])
    peaks = get_peaks(filename)

    print('Sample is %d seconds' % len(peaks))
    print('Minimum is', min(peaks))
    print('Maximum is', max(peaks))

    peaks = normalize(peaks)
    print(peaks)
```

Comment: I think this has been asked already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344888/getting-max-amplitude-for-an-audio-file-per-second?lq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304495/python-getting-the-amplitudes-of-a-sound-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the amplitude data from an mp3 audio files using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797934/get-the-amplitude-data-from-an-mp3-audio-files-using-python)

Answer (score 5):

Using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub), you can get `loudness`  and  `highest amplitude` of an `mp3` file very easily.  You can then use one of these parameters to make code/light react to that.

From the [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) website,

**AudioSegment(…).max**

The highest amplitude of any sample in the AudioSegment. Useful for things like normalization (which is provided in pydub.effects.normalize).

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/sound.mp3", format="mp3")    
peak_amplitude = sound.max
```

**AudioSegment(…).dBFS**

Returns the loudness of the AudioSegment in dBFS (db relative to the maximum possible loudness). A Square wave at maximum amplitude will be roughly 0 dBFS (maximum loudness), whereas a Sine Wave at maximum amplitude will be roughly -3 dBFS.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/sound.mp3", format="mp3")
loudness = sound.dBFS
```