# How to get number of Frames(or Samples) per sec or ms in a audio (.wav or .mp3) file?

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I've been observing an audio file under `scipy.io.wavfile`

which has a framerate of `44100 per sec or hz` and total frames are `9745238` and the duration of the audio is `220 secs` by the file properties but it should be `220.9804535147392` and has `2` channels.

after reading a file it returned me a `9745238 X 2` matrix of `16bit signed int` as expected

*where 1 column is channel 1 data and 2 column is the channel 2 data for respective 9745238 frames*

so my question is there any robust method find these values (with 1, 2 channel consecutively i.e. each row or the matrix) per second or millisecond?

any guesses?

**Edit 1**

I've referred to a very intuitive discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/388382/what-does-the-sample-rate-and-sample-size-of-audio-means)

and i guess all i need is **bitrate** which is `bitrate = sampleRate * bitDepth`
but how can i get **bit depth** is it `sample size / sample width` or something else.

Comment: Are you sure the duration is exactly 220 seconds? 9745238 at 44.1Khz would be 220.98 seconds.

Comment: yea, i guess it is that i saw the duration from the properties of the file, maybe it had rounded it.

Comment: @greg-449 check out the edit.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to find. Are you trying to divine the sample rate from the arrays?

Comment: @jaket yea you can say that, that how many arrays (rows) are happening per second or millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

So, I wanted number of bits per second and after doing some research i found that i needed the rate of each bit i.e. **bit rate** , and certainly  **bit depth** is the number of bits per sample (which is constant).

to understand this if we use the `wave` module to print the first frame of the file, we get something like this .

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

and as you can see that it is a `16bit-unicoded` string and after converting it into `16bit signed int` using `numpy`.

like `np.fromstring(wav.readframes(1), np.int16)`

it'll give you **[0 0]** that is 8 bits for each channel in the first frame.

and as the frameRate is `44100` , therefore `bitrate = frame_rate (44100) * bitDepth (16)` for each vector eg. [0 0], and we multiply this value by the number of channels (*in my case 2*) to get the answer with respect to the bits.

**Edit 1**

And Sample rate and frame rates are two different things, a frame is made up of number of samples, and sample_width is the size of each sample.

eg. consider an audio `_` as a sample representation and has `3` channels, `4` frames, then it will be represented something like this.

`[_ _ _]
 [_ _ _] 
 [_ _ _]
 [_ _ _]`

if you view the matrix using the `scipy` library then instead of `_` there will be numbers whose value will be according to decoded string and to put the statement in another way we can say that each element in the matrix is a sample.

so there are total 12 samples in the audio and if we suppose duration of the song to be, `1 sec` then the **`frame_rate`** will be `4hz` and **`sample_rate`** will be `12hz`.

for more information you can refer to the answers in these discussions.

1. [sound.stackexchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/42569/how-to-get-number-of-framesor-samples-per-sec-or-ms-in-a-audio-wav-or-mp3/42571#42571)
2. [theDontOvelookCommentsSection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797934/get-the-amplitude-data-from-an-mp3-audio-files-using-python/38798166?noredirect=1#comment82521029_38798166)
3. [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039846/what-do-the-bytes-in-a-wav-file-represent/13041339)